# Dynamic RewriteBase in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rule in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

I want to introspect the HTTP_HOST and if it starts with "localhost", I want:

```
RewriteBase /my-website/
```

Can I do that?

Comment: How about just dropping `RewriteBase`, thus enabling wildcardlike location?